# Is there any reason for why MySQL says "bye" when you exit it?

Tags: mysql

Whenever I exit MySQL, the program prints the message "Bye."

Is there any particular reason it does this?  e.g. so that scripts invoking `mysql` could guess as to the point in time when the program exits?  Or is it just a touch of humor on the developers' part?

I ask because I have a use case (which I cannot disclose the details of, for breach of contract) which requires me to eliminate this message, so I would like to know if it serves any practical purpose whatever before attempting to modify MySQL to remove the message.

Comment: It is just mysql trying to be nice.

Comment: Good Manners? :)

Comment: Lots of programs do this, not just MYSQL. Send your infeasible requirement back for review.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that it's to differentiate between aborting the program and exiting gracefully.

From [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/a533e2c786164af9bd276660b972d93649434297/client/mysql.cc#L1496):

```
  if (sig >= 0)
    put_info(sig ? "Aborted" : "Bye", INFO_RESULT);
```